Any New Selenium Versions for Chrome CDP version 126?
Today I create a small application with react js. I want to test my test cases with intel IDE (maven Project) with selenium. My Chrome Version is 126.0.6478.62.I run the maven project with intel IDE. But it gives error. The error message is below
[IDE Error Message] (https://i.sstatic.net/655RYNTB.png)
This is my pom.xml code
[pom.xml] (https://i.sstatic.net/xV85UTji.png)
Actually, I Update the new Version with Selenium using https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases
this git repository The New Version in the Repo Will Support only CDP Version 125.How Can I Fix this Problem.
I try with all new versions using this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases repository the Problem is My Chrome version is not compatible with this new version in selenium. As well as I Can't Downgrade my Chrome Version. Because I https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads?authuser=0 this site only shows up with 115 CDP Version and The latest versions shows as 126 and up versions.

Looks like selenium has to come up with the latest version to support CDP 126, where currently with the selenium latest version 4.21.0 it supports CDP 125. And yes can't downgrade chrome version to 125. As, its a warning the code works but with the warning message.

find new versions of selenium at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java or https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#beta
Sometimes newer versions comes at this site.
But today's update to 126.0.6478.115 is not yet.
